# Customizing CAInterAppAudioTransportView

Tags: ios, audiokit

I've been trying to customize CAInterAppAudioTransportView with no luck. I can't change the spacing between the buttons nor change the position of the timer.

Does anybody know if this customization is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they allow much control beyond colors: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudiokit/cainterappaudiotransportview

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll do my own. Thanks